# how to set text size according to browser size?

Tags: html, css

I am building a site,that need to be scaled according to the browser size.Basically 2 rows of 3 columns. Left and right columns have picture and middle column have text in it.I gave percent to the left and right and they are doing well,but how to give text in the middle column same treatment so the it changes its size according to the browser size?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser, if you are targeting modern browsers that allow CSS3, you can use the css media queries:

```
<link href="grid-978.css" media="all and (min-width: 1002px) and (max-width: 1247px)" rel="stylesheet">
```

This code loads the selected css only for that interval of screeen sizes.

You can see an example here: http://978.gs/

Then what you could do is adapt the different content to the viewport you are dispaying (this means the effective screen size that has your page to show, including scrollbar).

Comment: This is called [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)